# What kind of setter do I need write for backward compatibility?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm new in the OOP. Please, help me. I marked some property like "obsolete", and created 2 collections. What kind of setter do I need to write in these(obsolete) properties for backward compatibility (I use this property in the tests and in the old version of my product)?

```
[Obsolete("This is for backward compatibility with existing database records. Use Ids instead")]
[DataMember(Name = "Id")]
public Guid Id
{
    get { return Ids.FirstOrDefault(); }
}

[Obsolete("This is for backward compatibility with existing database records. Use Names instead")]
[DataMember(Name = "name")]
public string Name
{
    get { return Names.FirstOrDefault(); }
}

DataMember(Name = "Ids")]
public GuidCollection Ids { get; set; }

DataMember(Name = "names")]
public StringCollection Names { get; set; }
```

Comment: This really depends on how you populate these objects...which you don't appear to elaborate on.

Comment: Thanks, James, can you explain it a little deeper?

Comment: I was hoping you could do that....do you need the setter for these properties to be public? Are they set directly in code i.e. `object.name = "abc"`? Are they populated by a serializer? There just isn't a lot of information to go on is what I am saying...

Comment: yes, public and yes, they set directly in code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this,

```
[Obsolete("This is for backward compatibility with existing database records. Use Names instead")]
[DataMember(Name = "name")]
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return Names.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    set
    {
        Names = new StringCollection();
        Names.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: @Anatoly, here `value` is the keyword that obtains the assigned value of the `Name` property.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write setters.  If you are marking the properties obsolete, then that means you are recommending that they no longer be used going forward, but more importantly, leaving out the setters won't break anything that already *does* use the properties because any legacy code never had the setters to begin with.

Comment: OP should clarify but I'd guess he HAD setters for _old_ properties.

Comment: "*If you are making the properties obsolete, then that means you aren't using them any longer*" - not quite, as per the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22kk2b44(v=vs.90).aspx) marking something as obsolete means you are *recommending* that the developer no longer uses it. It's still perfectly acceptable for someone to use a property/method that's been marked as obsolete, the example given by the OP is a prime example (legacy system support).

Comment: Yes, but the more salient point I'm trying to make is that leaving out the setter won't break anything in the legacy code because there was never any setter to begin with.  But I will clarify.